# java.net.MalformedURLException While calling java web service

Tags: java, php, web-services

I have create a java web service. There is a method which accept a String parameter. It is as below.

```
public String checkSimilarity(String url)
{            
 try {
        input = ImageUtilities.readMBF(new URL(url));
        ..................//some code goes here
      }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

I called the above web service using php. My code is as below.

```
 $client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8080/imageCom/wsdl/CompareImage.wsdl");
   $stock ="http://localhost/pic/cc1.jpg";
   $values = $client->checkSimilarity($stock);       
  //print_r($values);
 foreach ($values as $key => $object) {
echo $object->object_property;
}
```

When I call this I get an exception "java.net.MalformedURLException". How can I solve this?

Comment: port needed at `$stock`?

Comment: @FranMontero I can't understand your question. what do you mean by ' 
port needed at $stock'? Can you explain that?

Comment: Did you check (with a debugger) what is "in" the string parameter `url`?

Comment: @VolkerK, should I do that in Java webservice or, inside the php?

Comment: @VolkerK actually the url value is null. I think it is an error in my php code. How can I pass the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I have bind the parameter incorrectly. In php to call the web service , it should be as below.

```
  $values = $client->checkSimilarity(array('url'=>$stock));
```